# Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f: I_n \to B$ and $f$ is onto, then $B$ is finite and $|B|\le n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is the problem from "How to Prove It. A Structured Approach" by Daniel. J. Velleman.

There were definitions:

- $I_n = \{ i\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}|i\le n \} $.
- A set $A$ is called finite if there is a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I_n \sim A$.

That's my proof by induction:

Base case: $n=0$, $f:I_0\to B$. Since $f$ is onto then $B = \varnothing$ so $|B| = 0$ and $|B| \le n$. And clearly $B$ is finite.

Induction hypothesis: let for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if $f:I_n\to B$, $f$ is onto tehn $B$ is finite and $|B| \le n$.

Induction step: suppose $f:I_{n+1} \to B$, $f$ is onto. Let $x = f(n+1)$, $x \in B$. Suppose $x^* \in B$, $x \ne x^* $ (if $x$ is the only element of $B$ then clearly $B$ is finite and $|B| \le n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}, n > 0$) so since $f$ is onto $\exists m: f(m) = x^* $. Let $f^{-1}(x) = I' = \{ k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} | f(k) = x \} $ and $I'' = I'\backslash \{ n + 1 \}$. Also let $B' = B \backslash \{x\}$ and define $g: I_n \to B'$

$$ g(j) = \begin{cases} f(j),&& j \notin I'' \\\ x^* && j \in I''\end{cases}$$

So we have $g:I_n\to B'$, $g$ is onto then by inductoin hypothesis $B'$ is finite and $|B'| \le n $. Since $B'$ is finite and $\{ x \}$ is also finite, then $B' \cup \{x\} = B$ is finite and $|B| = |B'| + |\{x\}| \le n + 1$

I'm not sure about clarity and correctness of this proof. I saw proof without induction after solving it in my way, but it didn't come to my mind. And now I just want to check this approach.